# How To make LinearLayout transparent background?

Tags: xamarin.android

I want to make transparent background in Linear Layout, I want to show rounder Dialog Box in Map, but my background is show white colour.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7I3y.png)

any body have any suggestion for this.

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle"   >

  <solid
      android:color="#000000" >
  </solid>

  <stroke
      android:width="2dp"
      android:color="#C4CDE0" >
  </stroke>

  <padding
      android:left="5dp"
      android:top="5dp"
      android:right="5dp"
      android:bottom="5dp"    >
  </padding>

  <corners
      android:radius="11dp"   >
  </corners>

</shape>

Answer (score 0):

You can set the background to `Dialog` for example like this:

```
View dialogView = LayoutInflater.From(this).Inflate(Resource.Layout.layout1, null);

Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
dialog.SetContentView(dialogView);
dialog.Window.SetBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.Transparent));
dialog.Show();
```